# How to add animation in text carousel?

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation, text, carousel

I'm making a text carousel and I want it to give some effect using animation. I know how to use animation but I don't know how can I apply animation in this case. If anyone can give me an example of how to add animation effect, I will modify my code. Thanks :)

See my fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/jyy64c1k/1/

My HTML:

```
<p id="hitTheBlock">
   REVEAL YOURSELF SOMEWHERE
</p>
```

My jQuery

```
(function(){

      var flipperContent = ['MAKE BIG DECISION','MAKE BIG MISTAKES','MAKE BIG INVENTIONS'];
      var index = 0;


      function flipperSlider(){

        var flipper = $('#hitTheBlock');
        var messageLibrary = flipperContent[index];
        flipper[0].innerHTML = messageLibrary;
        index++;

        if(index >= flipperContent.length){
            index = 0;
        }

       }

       setInterval(flipperSlider,4000);

})();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like one below:

**[DEMO HERE](https://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/jyy64c1k/2/)**

```
flipper.slideUp('400',function(){
     flipper[0].innerHTML = messageLibrary;  
}).slideDown('400');
```